# how to update wordpress options from multi dimentional array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Im working on a theme for wordrpess where i want to add an option admin page for the theme settings. Cant get my brain to work with the process. heres my code:

```
$option_settings = (array(
                array('Section1', array(
                    array(  'ID'=>'id_name1', 
                            'Label'=>'Title1', 
                            'Value'=>'The title1 bar',
                            'Desc'=>'Description Goes Here1',
                            'Type'=>'input_text',
                            'Button'=>'upload'
                    ),
                array('Section2', array(
                    array(  'ID'=>'id_name2', 
                            'Label'=>'Title2', 
                            'Value'=>'The title2 bar',
                            'Desc'=>'Description Goes Here2',
                            'Type'=>'input_text',
                            'Button'=>'upload'
                    ),
                ))
));

if (!get_option('my_option_settings')) {
add_option('my_option_settings',$option_settings);
}

$options = get_option('my_option_settings');

if ($_REQUEST['save_settings']) {

//this is where my brain snaps huhu 

}

echo '<form method="post" action="index.php" id="form_settings">';
echo '<p class="submit message"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="save_settings" /></p>';
foreach ($options as $section) {
echo '<h3>'.$section[0].'</h3>';
foreach ($section[1] as $option => $value) {
    switch($value['Type']) {
        case "input_text":
            echo '<p><strong>'.$value[Label].'</strong> <input type="text" name="'.$value['ID'].'" id="'.$value['ID'].'" value="'.$value['Value'].'" /></p>';
            break;
    }

}
echo '</form>';
```

my main concern here is how do i edit array inside an array and how to pass thru request. Any help is much appreciated Thanks in advance.

**Updated question:**

ok lets say that the $option-settings is the content of the options database from wordpress. The reason is i would like to have just 1 options in wordpress database and just store them thru array for more organize data.

first is get the value and assign it to a variable:

```
$fetchOption = get_option('my_option_settings');
```

now i will edit or update the array inside $fetchOption variable.

```
foreach ($options as $section) {
    foreach ($section[1] as $option => $value) {
        $value['Value'] = [$_POST[$value['ID']]];

    }

}
```

Last is how to put back the changed value into the $fetchOption variable and update back the database using update_options('my_option_settings', $fetchOption).

Is this appropriate or not? whats the best practice for this? I could just assign them to 1 option but its kinda messy i guess. thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Uhm. I **really** hope you already found an answer, but..since someone could need this info I'd like to add it here.

First of all, the [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51802/update-option-stored-in-multi-dimensional-array) to the resource.

Then, the answer I'm using as a "source":

> As far WordPress is concerned - your multi-dimensional array is *one* option.
>
> To update just part of the multi-dimensional array its necessary to retrieve the entire array, alter it accordingly and then update the entire array.
>
> Suppose your multi-dimensional array is as follows:
>
> ```
> my_options = array(
>   'option_a'=>'value_a',
>   'option_b'=>'value_b',
>   'inner_array'=>array(
>        'foo' => 'bar',
>        'hello' => 'world',
>    ),
>   'option_c'=>'value_c'
> )
> ```
>
> And suppose you want to update the value of the 'hello' option from 'world' to 'moon'
>
> ```
> //Get entire array
> $my_options = get_option('my_options');
>
> //Alter the options array appropriately
> $my_options['inner_array']['hello'] = 'moon';
>
> //Update entire array
> update_option('my_options', $my_options);
> ```

Hope this helps Stackoverflow visitors in managing multidimensional arrays when it comes to Wordpress options :)

Answer (score 0):

this example can help you;

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="four wide column">
        <?php


        if (isset($_POST)) {
            if (isset($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['location'])) {

                $locationArray = [];
                // this line of code checks if the option is an array or not

                $locationArray  =  is_array(get_option('book_location')) ? get_option('book_location') : [];
                // In case of multidimentional array you can push array to an array
                array_push($locationArray, $_POST['location']);
                // print_r($locationArray);
                update_option('book_location', $locationArray);
            }
        }

        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="eight wide column">
        <form class="ui form" method="post">
            <div class="red card">
                <div class="content">
                    <!-- <div class="header">Bird Name</div>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="category">location</span>
                        </div> -->
                    <div class="description">

                        <div class="field">
                            <label>Location</label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location Name">
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="extra content">
                    <div class="ui divider"></div>
                    <div class="right floated author">
                        <button class="ui button" type="submit">Add Location</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, showing why this is a correct solution to OP's problem. As it stands currently it's not very useful and might be downvoted and/or deleted.